# Microsoft Azure Entra user account does not exist in tenant

Tags: azure, saml

I have set up an Enterprise Azure Entra app with single site login SAML enabled.  I have set the assignment required property to "no".  But it only allows the account register with the app to login for all other accounts it says the account does not exist in the tenant "Default Directory".

How can I enable it so any Microsoft account can login to the app?

[image]

Comment: @Sridevi The SAML enterprise apps do not have that option when you register the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: Azure AD SAML applications are not designed to be multi-tenant by default. Refer this [**SO  Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74105942/multi-tenant-saml-sso-app-installed-with-oauth-flow) by AlfredoRevilla-MSFT

- SAML application in Azure AD is registered in a specific tenant and can only be accessed by users in that tenant.
- Hence, if you want other tenant users to access the SAML app then you can invite them as guest users in your Azure AD tenant and allow them to access the app.

***Go to users -> New user -> Invite external user***

[image]

[image]

***The user gets the invitation mail:***

[image]

Once the user accepts the invitation, the user will be added as Guest user in the tenant and will be able to access the SAML app:

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can make use of [**OpenID authentication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/architecture/auth-oidc), [**OAuth 2.0 authorization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-app-types) protocols **which supports multi-tenant applications.**